Metric in the Space of Continuous positives Functions
Let
E = $\{ f : \mathbb{R} \to ]0, +\infty[ \text{, continuous and } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f = 1 \}$ .
Prove that $d$  is a distance on $E$, where
$$d(f, g) = \left\| \frac{f - g}{\sqrt{f + g}} \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$$
If $d(f, g) = 0$, then by continuity, $f - g = 0$, so $f = g$.
It is trivial that $d(f, g) = d(g, f)$, but I am having some difficulties proving the triangle inequality.
